# Вывод без событий в GUI

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

Как в `Powershell / Windows.Forms` вывести или актуализировать текст без событий в GUI, просто по ходу работы скрипта или по времени?

Например, показывать постоянно время: `[datetime]::Now`

Или любой другой простой пример.

Comment: Но.. зачем?     15 символов

Comment: Как я понимаю, gui не обновляется, пока идёт выполнение длинного участка кода. Костыль: вставить в цикл `Application.DoEvents`. Лучше вынести этот код в отдельный поток/задачу. Или использовать async.